# Replace current url with document.URL

Tags: javascript, url, replace, window.location

I was trying to get the current URL and replace it with something else.
But my code does not work if x = document.URL, but for x = "String" everything works perfectly

```
function test(){

    var x = document.URL    
    var url = window.location.toString();
    window.location = url.replace( x , 'whatever');
}
test();
```

Thank you for helping me out

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you trying to do? `document.URL` is equal to `window.location.toString()`, so your code will actually do `document.location = "whatever"`

Comment: That's not what `replace` does.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @FAngel: I'm trying to replace the whole URL. instead of putting them in replace as a string, I wanted to set the whole URL in var x.

So I can change the URL even when it changes (e.g if a customer log in, the url changes)

Comment: `document.URL` is a simple string. `So I can change the URL even when it change` - not clear what do you mean here. You can do that without any x var.

Comment: If you put just a word or string in place of "whatever", it will just try to look for that file/path in the current location of where it is...for example: if u're on google.com and you put `document.location = "whatever"`, it will go to google.com/whatever, but if u put the entire URL: `document.location = "http://www.whatever.com"`, only then it will replace the whole URL. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: if I got a website which URL is for example
www.abc.de/customer2344/test/test2, 
www.abc.de/customer2342334r/test/test2, 
www.abc.de/customer2366666r/test/test2,

I try to get the link, whatever it may be, and replace it with something else.
thats why I thought about using a var, to be more flexible

Comment: @Chirag64: Thank you it work, but the www.whatever.com - site seems to be quiet bad.
my antivir just got an alert on this haha

Comment: So you need to write a function that will capture the part from the URL that says "customer2344" and replace only that part with the new part. A combination of substrings and indexOfs would help, might need to use RegEx in some cases. Depends on which site you're exactly trying this on.

Comment: LOL, I just meant that as an example, @ChristophHa, didn't realize it was an adware website. Sorry about that :P

Comment: I know, no need to be sorry :P

Comment: @Chirag64: your example with the whole URL really solved what I was trying to archive

 window.location = 'http://www.test111.com';

Comment: @FAngel: thank you a lot for your quick help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of the variables `url` and `x` are the same, so you're simply replacing the whole URL with 'whatever'. Why not just use `window.location = 'whatever'` instead?

If you want the whole URL to be replaced, you need to give a complete URL in the string where you've put `whatever`, otherwise it will act as a relative URL instead of an absolute one.

So try something like `window.location = "http://www.google.com"`

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `window.location.href = 'whatever'`. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

`window.location = 'whatever'` works too, but it's technically incomplete. Javascript will, however, implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

May be `window.location = 'whatever';` can help you?

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/69YRH/)

Comment: thank you, but this does not replace the whole URL, as I tried